# R: what is the parametrization of log-logistic distribution in dllog?

Tags: r, statistics, distribution

```
library(FAdist)
```

I'm using the `dllog` function in R, but I'm not sure what the exact parametrization of the log-logistic function it's using? Suppose I plot

```
kappa = 0.3
lambda = 4.5
plot(dllog(1:96, shape = kappa, scale = lambda), type = "l")
```

This looks completely different from this (I'm writing out the pdf and plugging in the same kappa and lambda values)

```
plot(1:96, (kappa/lambda)*(x/lambda)^(kappa-1)/(1 + (x/lambda)^kappa)^2, type = "l")
```

Comment: looking at the function `dllog` and `?dlogis` leads to `mydllog <- function(x, m, s) 1/x* 1/s * exp((log(x)-m)/s)* (1 + exp((log(x)-m)/s))^-2 ; plot(mydllog(1:96, s = kappa, m = lambda), type = "l", col="red")`